# What is the purpose of Python 3's `dict_values` type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does `myDictionary.values()` return a `dict_values` object as opposed to a `set` or `list` or `tuple`?

I don't see the advantage to the `dict_values` type and it causes issues when casting to other types, e.g.:

```
>>> np.array( {0: 0, 1: 1}.values() )
array(dict_values([0, 1]), dtype=object)
>>> np.array( list( {0: 0, 1: 1}.values() ) )
array([0, 1])
```

Why did Python's `.values()` go from using the more-compatible lists in Python 2 to returning its own custom object in Python 3?

Comment: `dict.values` runs on O(1) time, rather than O(n) time, without *forcing* you into its choice of data type.

Comment: So couldn't they just return a `generator`? Are there any other advantages?

Comment: This is part of a broader change in 3.x from lists to more memory-efficient types: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists. You can read more about it in [the relevant PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-3106/).

Comment: And also, if that is the case, how can I avoid iterating over it twice with `np.array( list( ...` ?

Comment: `generator` is just the type of object returned by a function defined by a `def` statement that uses `yield` statements; it's not an all-purpose iterator.

Answer (score 2):

There are several advantages:

1. `dict.values` runs in O(1) time, not O(n).
2. `dict.values` lets *you* choose if you want a `set` or a `list` or a `tuple`, etc, rather than picking the container for you.
3. `dict.values` returns an iterable which provides an iterator that that reflects the current values of the `dict`, not the values present when you called `dict.values`. For example:

   ```
   >>> d = dict(a=1, b=2)
   >>> dv = d.values()
   >>> list(dv)
   [1, 2]
   >>> d['c'] = 3
   >>> list(dv)
   [1,2,3]
   ```

   Note that we didn't have to call `d.values()` again for `list(dv)` to pick up the newly added value.